# Snowboard boot socks

Tags: skiing, snowboarding

I'll start practicing Snowboard and want to know what kind of socks are best. I have read on the Internet that can be a good idea to thin socks, but I'm not sure it's the right thing.

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange! Please don't ask shopping questions on this site. These question don't have any definite answers and are of little value to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following link - http://www.snowboarding-master.com/snowboarding-socks.html
it's from a well known snowboarding site.

the main answer is:

> For snowboarding you want to wear WOOL, SMARTWOOL or a Synthetic
>   material specifically made for skiing or snowboarding...Some Brand
>   Name examples of synthetic fabrics are HOLOFIBER, THERMASTAT or
>   MICROFLEECE
>
> For snowboarding, one pair of midweight socks is best... Do not wear 2
>   pairs of socks unless the base pair are very thin lightweight socks...

also take a look at this post - http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100116060636AAkOrH2